# Javascript define-then-call syntax

Tags: javascript, function, closures, call

Very straight-forward, so the question is why

```
(function(){ console.log('a'); }()); // 'a'
```

or

```
(function(){ console.log('a'); })(); // 'a'
```

work, but

```
function(){ console.log('a'); }() // SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

gives an error? What's the meaning behind this behavior? Or what's the purpose of those extra parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra parentheses convert the `function` into a *function expression* instead of a *function declaration*.

Only a function expression can be invoked immediately with the trailing `()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear explanation for that. JavaScript simply can't parse `function(){ console.log('a'); }()` successfully. This also happens with other examples, like this one:

```
1.toString();    // Syntax error
(1).toString();  // Works
```

An (working) alternative to your code would be (note the `!` at the beginning):

```
!function(){ console.log('a'); }()
```